# How to dynamically update the local development package files of NPM links in the vite project

Tags: vite, npm-link

I linked the local package in the vite project, but after modifying my local package, I need to delete the node_ Modules, execute pnpm install and restart again to get the latest package. Is there any way to dynamically update them?

[image]